# Django add field to existing model app

Tags: python, django

in my new Django app I use 3rd-part Photologue app.
This app works well, but I need to add some field in its model without change the original source code of Photologue app.

With this snippet, all works well, but maybe this is not the best solution:

```
Photo.add_to_class("link", models.URLField(max_leng.... ))
```

I've read some posts where I should use OneToOneRelationField ... but then, in django admin app, I will have two different form page of Photo and new PhotoLink class...

Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a `OneToOneField`, you can use your 'extension' model as an inline to the model you are extending. You do this by first un-registering the original admin class, and then overriding it with our variant:

```
from otherapp.admin import OriginalFooAdmin
from otherapp.models import Foo
from yourapp.models import YourExtension
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.unregister(Foo)

class ExtensionInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = YourExtension

class NewFooAdmin(OriginalFooAdmin):
    inlines = OriginalFooAdmin.inlines + [ExtensionInline]
admin.site.register(Foo, NewFooAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks, this methods in admin app work works well, but in template I need extra work.
Do you know add_to_class methods? Its the best option??

Comment: Using `add_to_class` means you can't use south migrations from the third-party app. Also, other people reading the code will need extra time to figure out where the field comes from; it could be anywhere in your codebase